# Field does not exists only in tree view

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

So I have this problem with a tree view.

If I want to add field name="work_order_id" I'm getting that this field does not exist. but if I click on record it opens me form view with this field existing? what is wrong with my tree view?

```xml
<record id="mrp_workorder_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">mrp.workorder.view.form</field>
    <field name="model">mrp.workorder</field>
    <field name="priority">15</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_production_workorder_form_view_inherit"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name="name" position="before">
            <field name="work_order_lots_ids" widget="one2many_list"/>
                <tree  editable="bottom">
                    <!--<field name="work_order_id"/>-->
                </tree>
        </field>
    </field>
</record>
```

```py
class WorkOrderLots(models.Model):
    _name = 'work.order.lots'
    _description = 'Work Order Lots'

    work_order_id = fields.Many2one('mrp.workorder')
    work_order_lot_id = fields.Many2one(
        'stock.production.lot', string='Work Order Lot',
    )
    quantity = fields.Float(string='Quantity', digits=(6, 2), required=False)

class MrpWorkorder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'mrp.workorder'


    work_order_lots_ids = fields.One2many(
        'work.order.lots', 'work_order_id',
        string='Field Names',
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Just changed the view to this.

```
<record id="mrp_workorder_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">mrp.workorder.view.form</field>
            <field name="model">mrp.workorder</field>
            <field name="priority">15</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.mrp_production_workorder_form_view_inherit"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <notebook position="inside">
                    <page string="Work Order Lots" name="work_order_lots">
                        <field name="work_order_lots_ids" widget="section_and_note_one2many" >
                            <form>
                                <group>
                                    <field name="work_order_lot_id"/>
                                    <field name="quantity" />
                                </group>
                            </form>
                            <tree string="Work Order Lotss" editable="bottom" >
                                <field name="work_order_lot_id"/>
                                <field name="quantity" />
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `widget="one2many_list"` attributes from field `work_order_lots_ids`

Replace following code from

```
<field name="work_order_lots_ids" widget="one2many_list"/>
    <tree  editable="bottom">
        <!--<field name="work_order_id"/>-->
    </tree>
</field>
```

to

```
<field name="work_order_lots_ids"/>
    <tree  editable="bottom">
        <field name="work_order_lot_id"/>
        <field name="quantity"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Comment: The thing is that i have error if i add this fields like this.raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Field `work_order_id` does not exists

Error in context:
View `mrp.workorder.view.form`
[view_id: 1072, xml_id: config_trikdis.mrp_workorder_view_form, model: mrp.workorder, parent_id: 771]
None" while parsing /home/antonp/workspace/Odoo12/sandas_addons/config_trikdis/views/mrp_workorder_view.xml:5, near
<record id="mrp_workorder_view_form" model="ir.ui.view">

Comment: @Chaban33 I have edited my answer and remove `work_order_id` field from tree view. When you save record, it will store current workorder id. Please try it again.

Comment: same error just now with work_order_lot_id, and if remove work_order_lot_id, same error with quantity. it's very strange because if I click on record it's opens me form view with all fields with values.